# CppCMS-Embedded 404

Tags: c++, cppcms

I am trying a simple example with CppCms and I would like to execute all my applications relative to the web application root. I don't want execute the application relative to the script path. Ex localhost: 8080/script-path/relative-path-to-my-application, and instead of this, I would like the path for my application would be like: localhost: 8080/relative-path-to-my-application. I would like to execute this application using the CppCMS-Embedded. I am trying a super simple example and I had no success. All the time I try the root url (http://localhost:8080/) I get a 404 error like that:

```
Connection          close
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Type        text/html; charset=utf-8
Server              CppCMS-Embedded/1.1.0
X-Powered-By        CppCMS/1.1.0
status              404 Not Found
Accept              text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding     gzip, deflate
Accept-Language     en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control       max-age=0
Connection          keep-alive
Cookie              _ga=GA1.1.541474771.1454701631
Host               localhost:8080
User-Agent         Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0
```

Below the code and config files that I made:

main.cpp:

```
#include <cppcms/application.h>
#include <cppcms/applications_pool.h>
#include <cppcms/service.h>
#include <cppcms/http_response.h>
#include <cppcms/url_dispatcher.h>
#include <cppcms/url_mapper.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "content.h"
   class my_app : public cppcms::application{
      public:
         my_app(cppcms::service& s) : cppcms::application(s){
               dispatcher().assign("",&my_app::well_come,this);
               mapper().assign("");
               mapper().root("");
    }
    void well_come(){
        content::index ci;
        ci.message = "Hello ";
        render("index",ci);
    }

  };
  int main(int argc,char ** argv){
    try{
        cppcms::service srv(argc,argv);
        srv.applications_pool().mount(
          cppcms::applications_factory<my_app>()
        );
        srv.run();
     }catch(std::exception const & e){
         std::cerr<<e.what()<<std::endl;
     }
}
```

config.js:

```
{
  "http" : {
      "script" : "/mb.fcgi",
      "rewrite" : [
          { "regex" : "/media(/.*)?", "pattern" : "$0" },
          { "regex" : ".*" , "pattern" : "/mb.fcgi$0" }
      ]
   },
   "service": {
      "api":"http",
      "port":8080
    },
   "views" : {
       "paths" : [ "./" ],
       "skins" : [ "my_app"],
    },
}
```

index.tmpl

```
<% c++ #include "content.h" %>
<% skin my_app %>
<% view index uses content::index  %>
<% template render()%>
  <html>
    <body>
      <h1><%= message %> World!</h1>
    </body>
  </html>
<% end template %>
<% end view %>
<% end skin %>
```

content.h

```
#include <cppcms/view.h>
namespace content{
   struct index : public cppcms::base_content{
     std::string message;
   };
}
```

What's I missing in my configurations? Why the CppCMS-Embedded is not routing for the web application root .
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some threads in the CppCms community, Artyom Beilis opened my mind for this issue.
All the time that I requested the root url like that http://domain.com/, I got a 404 error due to that the CppCms always expects at least some  mapping that is not empty, like "/" or any other string that start with "/" . The correct way is always to map to something that start with "/".
A good solution proposed by  Artyom Beilis is to keep the url's rewrite in the same form like the tutorial: [How to run the application at the root of the web server](http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/run_application_web_server_root#CppCMS-Embedded). And add a mapping that is not empty that matches with the default url, like that:

```
 dispatcher().assign("/",&my_app::well_come,this);
 mapper().assign("well_come","/");
```

This solution works pretty well for me =;)